# reset form element without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

As you might guess I'm building a small chat system, and I would like that when the user clicks enter the message would be sent and the text area cleared.

I'm using this jquery:

```
 jQuery('#my-form')[0].reset();
```

and it reloads the page which looks really noob.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#textbox1').val('');
```

Should clear a textbox

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your text-input/textarea is properly within a form, why not use:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear the box" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XbDXf/).

Or:

```
<button type="reset">clear the text</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XbDXf/1/).